# Slider with multiple elements

Tags: jquery, css, layout, slider

I'd like to create a slider like in these image galleries.
It should show multiple entries at a time, as shown in the following image:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/nTBPw.png
(@ILMV sorry, I'm not allowed to place it by myself..)

When I click on the right arrow it should slide ("iPhone-like") to the left so that you see 5, 6, 7 and 8.
The entries (imaged by numbers) are created dynamicly.

```
<div>
    <ul>
        <li>1</li>  <!-- ← visible -->
        <li>2</li>  <!-- ← visible -->
        <li>3</li>  <!-- ← visible -->
        <li>4</li>  <!-- ← visible -->
        <li>5</li>  <!-- ← not visible -->
        <li>6</li>  <!-- ← not visible -->
        <li>7</li>  <!-- ← not visible -->
        <li>8</li>  <!-- ← not visible -->
    </ul>
</div>
```

I know how a slider works and would be able to create one by myself, but I can't figure how to create that (CSS-)layout..

Thank you in advance

EDIT
to make that clear: the order is relevant because I'd like to build a "all of our customers" grid-like view, which are sorted by their titles.

Comment: Do you need the list items in *that* order? Because you used an `ul`, unordered you see, and if you want it that way its probably a little more complex. Use an `ol` if you want it ordered. Also, (I think it's because you're in a hurry) but you forgot your closing slash on the `li`!

Comment: Okay, to be clearer about what should be achieved by this :)

The numbers represent our customers logos, which are sorted by their names.  I used unorderd lists because the system itself is already sorted by the Quicksand Sort-Plugin (http://razorjack.net/quicksand/demos/one-set-clone.html) - so it souldn't really matter..?

And yep, I was in a hurry - of course the li-tags must be closed correctly :)

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your question is that you're unclear about whether you need the list elements in a particular order or not. Of course given you're already using jQuery there's no reason why you shouldn't be able to insert them in a manner which would be acceptable to you.

Anyway, I've created something simple with `float`s. Here's a simple demo: http://jsfiddle.net/vPGbf/

The crux of the whole thing (ignoring the really fancy CSS I've stuck in there) are some really simple `float`ed `li`, a absolute positioned `ol` and a outer `div` with `overflow` set to hidden to hide the other `li`s which you don't need yet. That's really it. Remember that the `ol`'s width have to be increased as you add in more elements, and that to do the sliding you should change the `left` value of the `ol`.

Comment: @scherii If you are asking for someone to help you debug your code I think it might be more appropriate to open another question, since that would be going outside the scope of this question.

Comment: I managed to create a solution with javascript/jQuery by wrapping every 8 elements in a div - I think this way it'll work as I though.
Thanks for your help and your time! I apologize for that I wasn't able to ask what I really needed, I wasn't sure about it myself.
If anyone needs to know how I did it, feel free to contact me.

Answer (score 1):

Multiple Elements Cycle Plugin

Provides a simple preview scrolling panel of list items. Shows the given range of li items from the middle (hiding the edges items) and allows scrolling left and right within the list. Does not handle automatic scrolling or wrapping items around.

https://github.com/willrossi/jQuery-Multiple-Elements-Cycle